# How to convert Object from UDF parameter to Excel Range in Excel-DNA?

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I am developing a simple Addin using Excel-DNA. I have written a below function, but I am finding difficulties in converting it to a Range object. Tried googling and not able to figure out. Can someone please help me

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Excel Range")]
public static string Concat2([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)] object rng)
{
    try
    {
       // Assuming i am calling this from Excel cell A5 as =Concat2(A1:A2)
        var app = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
        var r = app.Range[rng, Type.Missing];

        return r.Cells[1,1] + r.Cells[2,2]
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to convert to a Range? Your example just uses the values, which you get as an `object[,]` through a call to `ExcelReference.GetValue()`.

Comment: so that i can access it by .cells[row, col]

Comment: If you don't mark your function as `AllowReference=true` you will get an `object[,]` array with all the values from the input range. Note that it will be a 0-based array. Use `rng.GetLength(0 or 1)` to get the number of rows or columns.

Comment: Thanks Govert. Can you please give an example for this, i am looking to iterate through cell values

Answer (score 2):

You should rather get the values directly from the input parameter, without getting the Range COM object. It's also much more efficient doing it that way.

Your simple function might then look like this:

```
    public static object Concat2(object[,] values)
    {
        string result = "";
        int rows = values.GetLength(0);
        int cols = values.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                object value = values[i, j];
                result += value.ToString();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Typically you'd want to check the type of the `value` object, and do something different based on that. The `object[,]` array passed from Excel-DNA could have items of the following types:

- `double`
- `string`
- `bool`
- `ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelError`
- `ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelEmpty`
- `ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelMissing` (if the function is called with no parameter, as `=Concat2()`).

If you change the signature to have a single parameter of type `object` (instead of `object[,]`), like this:

```
    public static object Concat2(object value)
```

then, depending on how the function is called, you might get one of the above types as the `value` or you might get an `object[,]` array as the `value`, so your type checks would look a bit different before you do the iteration.

Comment: How to deal with `object[,]` arrays containing `int`'s that I want to get back as `int`s ? (I mean without getting back a `double` that one "converts" to `int` etc.)

Comment: Excel represents all numbers as doubles. If you want to interpret the numbers as it's, the conversion must happen in the add-in somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my F# addin I have a function that does that (I use this function mainly to extract the displayed values of dates):

```
[<ExcelFunction(Description="Returns what is currently displayed as text.", IsMacroType=true)>]
let DISPLAYEDTEXT ([<ExcelArgument(Description="Cell", AllowReference=true)>] rng : obj) =
    app().get_Range(XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, rng, true)).Text
```

where app is:

```
let app()= ExcelDnaUtil.Application :?> Excel.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
[ExcelFunction(IsMacroType = true)]
public static double GetBackColor([ExcelArgument(AllowReference=true)] object cell)
{
    ExcelReference rng = (ExcelReference)cell;
    Excel.Range refrng = ReferenceToRange(rng);
    return refrng.Interior.Color;
}
```

and this is the helper function

```
private static Excel.Range ReferenceToRange(ExcelReference xlRef)
{    
    Excel.Application app = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
    string strAddress = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, xlRef, true).ToString();
    return app.Range[strAddress];
}
```